# Use a Virtual machine for learn how to install Archlinux for beginner?

Tags: virtual-machine, archlinux, system-administration

I'm a newbie in sysadmin.
I have a laptop from my school with windows7/opensuse on grub.
I would like now to install archlinux however I would like to avoid every risk of error that will delete my existing partition. (Because it will be very annoying for the rest of my year).
So that's why I would like to know if experiment how to install Archlinux using virtual machine will provide me "useful experience" for install on my my real computer ?
Does the virtual machine simulate installation step as a real computer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be on Superuser, but I'll answer it anyway.

For most of the trip, a virtual machine will be sufficient for you to get close with the way Arch installs, except for the exact section it worries you: partition management. However, you could try to replicate your current environment on the virtual machine (dualboot win/suse) and then install arch on the same machine, that would be educational.